# Retrieve list of weekdays for any case

Tags: python, algorithm

Hi everybody I have a small issue of coding:
I have a list of numbers from `0` to `6` that represent days of the week from Sunday to Saturday
So `Sunday = 0` and `Saturday = 6` 
So the list is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

There is no problem to retrieve the list between two days (or number) if the from < to.
example:
from `Monday= 1` to `Thursday= 4` there are these numbers included : `[1,2,3,4]`

Problems come when you have to retrieve the list of days when from > to:
example:
from `Friday = 5` to `Tuesday =2` we need to catch this list : `[5, 6, 0, 1, 2]`

Do you have idea how can I code an algorithm or a function that will give me a list of days (here numbers)  to include if I give a number "from" and a number "to" whatever "from" is inferior or superior to the "to" value.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You might look into the datetime library to work with comparing dates.

Comment: No idea what are you trying to achieve, but it looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
def getweekdays(frm, to):
    days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    if frm <= to:
        return days[frm:to+1]
    else:
        return days[frm:] + days[:to+1]
```

(I haven't checked the code, but you get the idea :) )

Comment: As `[from:to]` excludes the `to` part, you should do `[from:to + 1]`. I just checked, it won't return an `IndexError` even if you select an outer bound index anyways.

Comment: Thanks IMCoins, I've changed it

Comment: `from` is a keyword in Python, don't use it as a varibale name.

Comment: Psytho, thanks (I only wanted to show the idea, but I've changed it anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest aproach for this would be:

```
day = first_day
while int day != last_day:
    interval_days.add(day)
    if day > 6:
        day = 0
```

Initialize the day counter at the bottom limit of the day, then keep increasing the counter until the day matches the top limit, if it goes over the biggest day (6) you set it back into the first day of the week(0).

Comment: For an answer, your code has a way too much issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing:

```
s = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
days_of_week = dict(zip(['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'th', 'fri', 'sat'], s))
def get_days(day_range):
   return range(days_of_week[day_range[0]], days_of_week[day_range[-1]]+1) if days_of_week[day_range[0]] <= days_of_week[day_range[-1]] else s[days_of_week[day_range[0]]:]+s[:days_of_week[day_range[-1]]+1]

ranges = [['fri', 'tue'], ['th', 'sat'], ['mon', 'th']]
print(list(map(get_days, ranges))))
```

Output:

```
[[5, 6, 0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
days_of_week = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
day_1 = 5
day_2 = 2

def days_needed(days_of_week, day_1, day_2, rollover=True):
    if rollover:
        day_list = days_of_week[day_1:day_2 - 1:-1]
    else:
        day_list = days_of_week[day_1:day_2 + 1]
    return day_list

day_list = days_needed(days_of_week,day_1,day_2,rollover=True)

print(day_list)
```

This should do it. Let me know if you need any tweaking.